# Adding a Sample Space to a Venn Diagram in R

Tags: r, venn-diagram, jupyter-irkernel

I am trying to insert of a simple Venn diagram in an jupyter notebook on R. I have been able to generate a simple 2-set diagram using the VennDiagram library. However I can't seem to figure out how to work the triple diagram in way that yields 2 intersecting sets that are in a subset of another larger set.

Maybe I'm using the wrong library?

**Edit:**

This is for an illustration, I just need to draw an example of a Venn Diagram. The data would be something like:

S=(1,2,3)

A=(1,2)

B=(2,3)

Comment: post your data using `dput(data)`

Comment: I should have been a little more clear with my question. There is no data, this is for a simple example. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest development version of my r package [eulerr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=eulerr) is now able to take a list of sample spaces as input. It, however, produces euler diagrams (proportional Venn diagrams) (which is why your specifications won't result in two diagrams intersecting within another).

```
# devtoools::install_github("jolars/eulerr")

library(eulerr)

ll <- list(S = c(1, 2, 3), A = c(1, 2), B = c(2, 3))

fit <- euler(ll)

plot(fit)
```

[image: euler diagram 1]

If you want two intersecting circles within a third, try the following:

```
plot(euler(c(S = 5, "A&B&S" = 3, "A&S" = 1, "B&S" = 1)))
```

[image: intersecting euler diagram]